# Using XPath to POS in iMacro, getting runtime error

Tags: xml, xpath, web-scraping

When I try use the XPath expression

```
//a[starts-with(@href, 'mailto')]/text()
```

it gives me the list I need

but when I put the same XPath expression in iMacros Editor show as

```
TAG XPATH="(//a[starts-with(@href, 'mailto')]/text()" EXTRACT=TXT
```

I get the error "RuntimeError: incorrect XPath expression: (//a[starts-with(@href, 'mailto')]/text(), line: 2"

What am I doing wrong? I look forward to your help!

Comment: Why there is unclosed `(` at the beginning of your XPath? What happen if you remove it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're missing a closing parenthesis after text()

Change:

```
TAG XPATH="(//a[starts-with(@href, 'mailto')]/text()" EXTRACT=TXT
```

To:

```
TAG XPATH="(//a[starts-with(@href, 'mailto')]/text())" EXTRACT=TXT
```

Comment: That fixed it, thank you! But now its saying 

RuntimeError: ambiguous XPath expression: (/html/body//a[starts-with(@href, 'mailto')])

Comment: Do me a favor and take out the outside parenthesis altogether like this:

TAG XPATH="//a[starts-with(@href, 'mailto')]/text()" EXTRACT=TXT
and tell me if that works.  All of the iMacro/XPATH examples I can find are not enclosed in parenthesis.